# GMRES Matlab 'tol' parameter

Tags: matlab, gmres

I need to use GMRES solver in MATLAB, and I need to play around with the codes parameters and I had a very simple question about its usage.

The documentation of the solver [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gmres.html) mentions a parameter `tol` which they 
do not seem to have defined except that the defuault value is $10^{-6}$.

What is this number? There don't seem to be any definitions of this anywhere 
on the web.

Is it the upper-bound on $\frac{||b-Ax_k||}{||b||}$ where we are solving
$Ax=b$ and $x_k$ is the current GMRES iterate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed a tolerance on the relative residual $$ ||b-Ax_k|| / ||b||$$

In the webpage that you mention, you can find this information (very implicitly)

> [x,flag,relres] = gmres(A,b,...) also returns the relative residual
>   norm(b-A*x)/norm(b). If flag is 0, relres <= tol. The third output,
>   relres, is the relative residual of the preconditioned system.

Hope it helps!